# plt (matplotlib) not displaying in a new window

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, subplot, canopy

I am trying to subplot two images **myImage** and **reflectanceImage** using `matplotlib` and `plt` , the problem is that the figure is displayed in the console not in a new window, I need to have the figure in a new seperate window in order to save it and use it outside the code.

I beleive the problem is actually concerned with the version i'm using of **Linux (Ubuntu)** ? Or am I missing some line of code ?

```html
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    
    img_directory = "/XXX/XXX/IMG_XXX.TIF"

    myImage=cv2.imread(img_directory)

    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(221), plt.imshow(myImage),plt.title('Original Image')
    plt.subplot(222), 
    plt.imshow(np.array(reflectanceImage).reshape(1280,960).T),plt.title('Reflectance')p
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: which backend are you using?

Comment: Excuse me I'm a newby I don't understand that question ? What backend am I using ?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend

Comment: What Canopy version and what Python version?

Comment: @JonathanMarch Python 2.7 and Canopy 1.7.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `matplotlib`, you need to show the image using `plt.show()` unless you are not in interactive mode:

```
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(sample_image) 
plt.show()  # display it
```

*Note*: Be aware that you don't have to show the image in order to save it.

```
plt.savefig('image.png')
```

Answer (score 2):

go to

```
Tools -> Preferences -> IPython consol -> Completion Type
```

set it to `graphical`

Comment: Thank you for younr answer, I am using Canopy as an IDE and I don't find IPython consol in Edit  -> Preferences !

Answer (score 0):

By default, Canopy runs its IPython kernel in pylab qt mode; in this mode, windows do pop up in a new window. Because they are not doing this for you, it seems likely that for some reason in the past you changed the setting to pylab inline mode. (Perhaps because you wanted to run a TK program, as [here](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469880-Using-Tkinter-Turtle-or-Pyglet-in-Canopy-s-IPython-panel)?)

Please reset it to qt (Edit=>Preferences=>Python=>backend=qt). Does it now act as expected?

BTW, [the current version of Canopy is 2.1.3](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469570-Installing-a-new-Canopy-version).